# Improvised reach weapons

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, improvised-weaponry

Can you use the rules for improvised weapons and have a large item, such as a 10 feet pole arm to gain reach and threaten a larger area?

Comment: You may've meant 10-ft. pole instead of 10-ft. pole *arm*, but I took the question at face value anyway. I urge you to keep the question as-is even if you meant something different. The question's more interesting that way.

Comment: Alright, I missread what you said but it is now as normal again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The DM can permit some improvised weapons to have reach

While the *Player's Handbook* describes [improvised weapons](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/weapons.html#improvised-weapons) (113), *Complete Warrior* on Improvised Weapons summarizes those rules and expands them, saying

> As detailed in the *Player’s Handbook*, objects not crafted to be used as weapons may nonetheless find use in combat.…
>
> Any creature using an improvised weapon—from a broken bottle to a barstool—in a fight is considered to be nonproficient with it and thus takes a −4 penalty on attack rolls made with it. An improvised weapon scores a threat (a possible critical hit) on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a critical hit. An improvised thrown weapon has a range increment of 10 feet.
>
> What about fighting with ladders, wagon wheels, or coils of rope? In the hands of a determined (or desperate) individual, these oddly shaped objects offer a wide variety of options in combat. … [one of which may be…]
>
> **Reach:** Long objects (such as ladders) have reach, allowing a Small or Medium character to strike at opponents up to 10 feet away (but not at adjacent foes). These objects are treated as two-handed weapons. (158-9)

However, I suspect—as the question's example posits using a pole arm as an improvised weapon—that you're *not* thinking about bonking a dude with a ladder or the ubiquitous 10-ft. pole but, instead, about smacking a dude some distance away with your non-reach-yet-hafted [halberd](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/weapons.html#halberd) or [spear](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/weapons.html#spear). In such a case, first the DM decides if that object that's crafted to be a weapon can *also* be an improvised weapon then, second, the DM decides if the weapon-that's-an-improvised-weapon gains reach.

(The DM is wise to be wary of allowing objects crafted to be weapons to *also* be used as improvised weapons. For example, allowing weapons to function as improvised weapons means a crossbowman now threatens squares—and can make attacks of opportunity—by clubbing folks with his crossbow-as-an-improvised weapon, eliminating one of a low-level ranged combatant's primary weaknesses.)

Comment: The question was about a person that was using AoO:s to take 5ft steps (with evasive reflexes), so just holding a pole offers a -4 but gives reach as a improvised weapon. 
Said person also has a feat that allows him/her to take an AoO everytime someone attacks, effectivly making him/herself immortal to normal attacks

Comment: @Simon (If one of those is the feat Robilar's Gambit, remember that that feat says to "[r]esolve your attack of opportunity [or whatever you've substituted for an attack of opportunity] *after* your foe’s attack." (Emphasis and editorializing mine.))

Comment: No, unfortunately not its a homebrew feat, perhaps I should start a new question on the subject?http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Deflect_Attack_(3.5e_Feat)
Are homebrew feats okey to bring into here for questions? 
Its more of a general question on the flow of feats and their interaction with eachother but the example I have uses said homebrew feat

Comment: @Simon It's totally okay to post question about homebrew material as long A) there's a problem, and B) context's provided. Expect disagreement as to how the feat works, though.

Comment: @Simon Consider: Reach weapons usually don't let the user attack adjacent squares. A long pole (a polearm) would have reach, but be useless against adjacent creatures. A short pole (a staff) could attack adjacent creatures but not have reach. If an opponent is adjacent to the character, then even with that feat he would not be able to *use* his AoO's because his weapon cannot reach. Also, you only get 1 AoO per turn (or a small handful, with Combat Reflexes). The "RAW" principle can still apply to homebrew, and the feat does not grant extra AoO... All assuming he wants to attack.

Comment: @Simon Similarly, you only get a single 5' step per turn, and Evasive Reflexes doesn't have any language allowing you to circumvent that limit. If you do post a question like "how to handle this feat/situation" please @ me, so i can move these comments there.

Comment: @tzxAzrael The question has been asked and I have you on the notifications