# Can a halfling bard with the Taunt feat use a Versatile Performance (Oratory) to demoralize an enemy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, skills, bard, halfling

Can a halfling bard with the **Taunt** feat use a **Versatile Performance (Oratory)** to demoralize an enemy via the **Bluff** skill?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie meta question, OP meant to use the Act version of Versatile Performance, should we do edits to make it more pertinent or leave this as is? I ask because it *could* come up if someone is using a search function

Comment: @Ifusaso I'm not sure I understand. Did the OP clarify somewhere that Oratory is a mistake and they meant Act? Otherwise, it's fine as-is; searches for “Act” will still find this page because it's in the answers.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie yeah in the Answer comments. Regardless, you're probably right about the search.

Comment: @Ifusaso Ah, I see! It could go either way. I'm tempted to say to edit it for correctness, but then the answers need adjusting too, and the end result won't change that the asker has already been well-helped. It could go either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, you cannot use Bluff to Intimidate with Versatile Performance (Oratory)

### but you *could* with Versatile Performance (Act, Comedy, Sing, or String)

Oratory only applies to Diplomacy and Sense motive, the other 4 perform types listed can be used with Bluff.

[Taunt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/taunt) does not affect your Intimidate skill, it simply allows Bluff to be used in a way that duplicates one function of Intimidate.

[Bards'](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard) Versatile performance allows them to use the "his bonus in that skill in place of his bonus in associated skills". You're still rolling Bluff, not Perform. You just use your Perform modifier.

In summary, by taking Taunt you gain the capacity to demoralize using Bluff with your Perform (Act, Comedy, Sing, or String) bonus.

Comment: oops! I meant acting! but you answered it anyway :)

Comment: Haha yeah now I'm sitting here wondering what a String Perform Bluff looks like and how you Taunt with it.

Answer (score 2):

## No

The [bard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard)'s extraordinary ability [versatile performance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard#TOC-Versatile-Performance-Ex-) when picked for the skill Perform (oratory) only allows the bard to substitute his Perform (oratory) skill bonus when making Diplomacy and Sense Motive skill checks, not when making Bluff skill checks. To use the Perform skill bonus instead of the Bluff skill bonus (such as when using the feat [Taunt](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/taunt)), pick instead for the category of versatile performance act, comedy, sing, or string.

(Presumably, the Bluff skill is included among the skills that can be used with Perform (string) because Perform (string) includes being able to play the [lyre](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/lyre-of-building). Those *Pathfinder* guys are *hilarious*.)

Comment: oh darn! I meant Acting!

Comment: @FrancisJohn [Sometimes typos make better questions.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84394/8610)